print media using headers and footers when content flows into more pages
I am having a hard time with this one. I am trying to generate a pdf using html. The catch is that it must include a header and footer on every page, meaning space needs to be allocated for that together with the content. If the mix of all 3 exceeds page size, the content should flow into another page.
I tried the table method where I used thead and tfoot to keep the header and footer on each page.
<table>
  <thead><tr><td>
    <div class="header-space">&nbsp;</div>
  </td></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>
    <div class="content">...</div>
  </td></tr></tbody>
  <tfoot><tr><td>
    <div class="footer-space">&nbsp;</div>
  </td></tr></tfoot>
</table>
<div class="header">...</div>
<div class="footer">...</div>

// CSS
.header, .header-space,
.footer, .footer-space {
  height: 100px;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

It sort of works, but it has too much trouble splitting content in a sensible way and totally bugs out when the tbody happens to include another table. It starts overlapping with the header and footer.
I then tried the hands on css way using @page and page-break-inside way to handle things, but I ran into the same issues where it was really hard to get the headers/footers to not overlap with the content, particularly when it runs into tables. They just wont split right and end up overlapping.
<style>
   @page {
    size:A4;
   }

   @media print {

    .header {
      position: fixed;
      top:0;
    }
            
    .footer {
      position: fixed;
      bottom:0;
    }

    .page
    {
      height:auto;
      padding-top: 200px;
      padding-bottom: 200px;
      page-break-inside: auto;
    }

  }
</style>
<div class="page">...content</div>
<div class="page">...content</div>
<div class="page">...content</div>
<div class="header'></div>
<div class="footer'></div>

I am not sure if these setups have ever actually worked for someone. I am thinking of just doing this through javascript. Any thoughts?

The CSS page rule is designed for setting page layout, but fixed headers and footers can sometimes conflict, especially with complex content like nested tables. You can try an approach with a fixed margin for @page to reserve header and footer space while avoiding position: fixed in the header and footer elements themselves.
But honestly I'd just use a JS library like html2pdf.js [link] https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/
